# Maven Java EE and module project pom

Tags: maven-2, maven

i am new to maven.

i have a Java EE Web project and a model project,web project is depend on model because module has some standard classed which need to be jar in web.

web needs model jar file.

how can i write the 2 projects which one is depend on another ?

give me a sample coding on both project pom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical maven multi-modules project structure would involve *3* modules here: an **aggregating** parent module (allowing to start a multi-module build on all modules), the model module and the web module. Something like this:

```
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── mywebapp
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           └── webapp
│               ├── index.jsp
│               └── WEB-INF
│                   └── web.xml
└── pom.xml
```

Where the parent `pom.xml` (at the root) would be like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>Q4176120</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Q4176120 - Parent POM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>mywebapp</module>
    <module>mymodule</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

The `mymodule/pom.xml` would be a regular POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>Q4176120</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <!--groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId--> <!-- inherited -->
  <artifactId>mymodule</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Q4176120 - Module</name>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And `mywebapp/pom.xml` would declare a dependency on the mymodule artifact:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>Q4176120</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <!--groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId--> <!-- inherited -->
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Q4176120 - Maven Webapp</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mymodule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Q4176120</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

With this structure, you can start a multi-modules build from the parent directory i.e. run a goal on all modules (and maven will calculate the right build order):

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Q4176120 Parent POM
[INFO] Q4176120 Module
[INFO] Q4176120 Maven Webapp
[INFO]                                                                         
...
```

Note that I also used **inheritance** in the above samples (`mymodule` and `mywebapp` **inherit** from a parent that is declared in the `<parent>` element) so that I can group common parts in a parent POM and avoid repeating things. This is not mandatory, you can use aggregation without inheritance but this is very handy and aggregation and inheritance often go together in practice.

#### Resources

- Maven Documentation

  - [Project Inheritance vs Project Aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation)
- Maven Book

  - [3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit.html)

Comment: "aggregating parent" is ambiguous, it's either an aggregating or a parent project. In this example an aggregator could wrap the parent and another project, e.g. a library which isn't published to a repository or an integration test project.

Answer (score 0):

You create 2 maven projects: web project and jar project. web project will depend on the model project. So you will add the model project as a dependency in the web projects pom.xml

I suggest you read maven basics here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/

You model project pom.xml might look like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>>model-module</artifactId>
<name>My Model Module</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Your web app pom.xml might look like this. notice the dependencies section

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>>my-web-app</artifactId>
<name>My First Web Application</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
      <artifactId>model-module</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: in model i can use <packaging>jar</packaging> instead of <packaging>war</packaging> right ?  Is it important to have <packaging>pom</packaging>  ?

Comment: yep that is a copy/paste bug. corrected it now. go through the book i mentioned and you will understand if you need pom packaging or not